# How to get rid of Garbage value of char* dynamically allocated

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, malloc

I am trying to figire out how to not have garbage values in dynamically allocated char* str.

```
 char* str = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
```

since I want to use this char* to concatenate strings after, so I want to know how to not to have garbage value like below,

```
printf("str looks like this %s\n",str);
```

then output is

```
譁�蟄怜
```

Also, this happens when I am using Ubuntu, but does not happen with mac.
How do I make sure that it does not have garbage values so that I can concatenate nicely later?

Comment: Consider calloc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most expensive way is to use `calloc` function.

```
char* str = calloc(10, sizeof(*str));
```

The fastest way:

```
char* str = malloc(10 * sizeof(*str));
*str = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... how to not to have garbage value ...
> How do I make sure that it does not have garbage values so that I can concatenate nicely later?

Use `calloc()` to zero fill the allocated memory.

```
char* str = calloc(10, sizeof *str);
if (str) {
  printf("str looks like this <%s>\n",str);
}
```